# A different line for every 5 row ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, each

Is there a code I can use to print a default line for every 5 row I print out when I'm using

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
<%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

So when it print it out, it will look something like this:

- title1
- title2
- title3
- title4
- tilte5

  --------------- (hr)
- title6
- title7
- title8
- title9
- title10

  ---------------- (hr)

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `each_slice` for something like this.

```
<% @post.each_slice(5) do |posts| %>
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
       <%= post.title %>
    <% end %>
    <hr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why do you prefer using each_slice instead of in_groups_of ?

Comment: Probably because `each_slice` is a Ruby core method, whereas `in_groups_of` reuires Rails. And in this example it is even shorter, since you would have to call `in_groups_of(5, false)` instead of just`each_slice(5)`.

Comment: @spickermann, You got it. While I do like Rails helpers and definitely use them where needed, if the same functionality exists in `ruby`, I do tend to go that route. In fact, `in_groups_of` uses `each_slice`. If you do not need a filler that `in_groups_of` provides, it would probably be best to go with `each_slice`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 'in_groups_of' method.

http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of

This method splits and iterates an array in groups of a given number of elements.

Comment: Thats just what i'm looking for! Thanks. Also if someone else have this problem, then this video have some good examples how to use in_groups_of http://railscasts.com/episodes/28-in-groups-of?view=comments